# the react browser router accept one route, not nested routes, it is working in localhost but in hosted firebase site not working, what is the problem?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

I have a react app created by create-react-app, I am using BrowserRouter and Switch for handling routes, and I am hosting the app to firebase hosting, the problem is in localhost routes like /route and /route/:id working fine but when I deploy the app, just /route works fine, the others stuck on white page! firebase.json has {"source": "**","destination": "/index.html"} and it is not working, what is the problem?

I am trying to handle /route/:id with BrowserRouter and I expect that the page loads fine, but now the route /route/:id stuck on white page and it is not working!

Comment: I don't know why you want to deploy on firebase, whereas Vercel has a great support and it's free also for deploying.

Comment: Also you can check developer console in the white page whether there is any error.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description the route should work in Firebase hosting too. It is simply a CDN for built JS files, the same as in localhost.

Seems you have some stale files in Firebase. Try to check:

1. `firebase.json` and the path from which JS files are uploaded (under the `"public"` prop), for example:

```
{
      "target": "web-site-1",
      "public": "web-site-1/build",
      "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
```

2. Before uploading web-site to Firebase hosting it should be built with `npm run build`.